# Thymeleaf Spring th:field Error at validation of form

Tags: java, spring, forms, maven, thymeleaf

today I want to make a searchfunction/searchform for an application called "Videoshop".

So my idea was a little tool with helps the user to get the results easier, without searching/scrolling (For example Last Action Hero -> if we type "Hero", it will show us Last Action Hero)

It's using Spring(-Boot) v1.4.1; Maven 4.0.0 and Jdk 1.8.
I already read the other problems here on stackoverflow, but their problems are different to mine. The confusing part is my friend gets the same error (He uses MAC OSX and I WIN10, so I guess it's not the OS, noticed that JVM is independent form plattform).

Now that's my dvdCatalog.html where the SearchForm is located:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/style.css" />
    <title th:text="${title}">Katalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all">
    <header>
        <h1 th:text="${title}">Katalog</h1>
    </header>
    <nav th:include="navigation :: navigation">
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="search">
                <font color="black">Geben Sie den Suchbegriff unten ein.</font>
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/searchResult}" th:object="${SearchForm}"  method="post">
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" value="Suchbegriff" th:field="*{searchtext}"/>
                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('searchtext')}" th:errors="*{searchtext}">Falsche Eingabe</p>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Senden"  />
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
```

The error I get is "Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (discCatalog:30)".

So if remove th:field, the page works but then I get another error. Something with my validation is wrong. 
Here the exerpt from CatalogController.java:

```
@RequestMapping("/searchResult")
public String searchResult(@ModelAttribute("SearchForm") @Valid SearchForm SearchForm, Model model) {
    String query = SearchForm.getSearchtext();
    model.addAttribute("catalog", videoCatalog.findByName(SearchForm.getSearchtext()));

    return "discCatalog";
}
```

And finally SearchForm.java:

```
package videoshop;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

 public class SearchForm {
 @NotNull
  private String searchtext;

  public String getSearchtext(){
    return this.searchtext;
    }

  public void setSearchtext(String searchtext){
    this.searchtext = searchtext;
    }

 }
```

So I think maybe SearchForm.java is to easy/bad I don't know and thats the reason I get errors. 
The other point is, if I remove th:field, I get the error that SearchForm.searchtext must not be null, validation error.
I would be really happy if you could help me with that!

Comment: At first glance, I can't see what's wrong. Try adding a `BindingResult` to the controller to see what's wrong and add a debug breakpoint directly on the first line:
`public String searchResult(@ModelAttribute("SearchForm") @Valid SearchForm SearchForm, Model model, BindingResult result) {` This usually gives a clear indication of what is wrong

Comment: Thanks for the answer.